# Audio Buffer modification in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio

I want to read the Audio File buffers and save them to a new file after modification. What is the best way to get the buffers in an array and modify them ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you specify which type of modifications you want?

Comment: i want to add a delay signal to that buffer to get the echo like effect. Plz post some sample code if possible. thanks..

Comment: can you show what you have tried? What research have you done? What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can look in here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html
to get good grip of audio manipulation concept.